# Recursion…I'm stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

The problem goes like :

> Print a sequence of numbers starting with N, without using loop, in which
>
> A[i+1] = A[i] - 5,  if  A[i]>0, else A[i+1]=A[i] + 5  repeat it until
> A[i]=N

```
So for input = 16 
output is 16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16
input = 10 
output is 10 5 0 5 10
```

I am trying to analyse the solution how it is working once the number gets negative .

Here is the solution :

```
def print_pattern(n):
    print(n, end=' ')
    if n > 0:
        print_pattern(n - 5)
    else:
        return
    print(n, end=' ')

T = int(input())

for case in range(T):
    N = int(input())
print_pattern(N)
print()
```

Comment: When it gets negative, `if n > 0` is false, so it just returns instead of recursing.

Comment: Hi Harsh. Welcome to Stack Overflow, please make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting.

Answer (score 0):

As described, this appears to be an infinite recursion.  For input = 16:

```
16 -> 11 # A[i+1] = A[i] - 5 (> 0)
11 -> 6  # A[i+1] = A[i] - 5 (> 0)
6 -> 1   # A[i+1] = A[i] - 5 (> 0)
1 -> -4  # A[i+1] = A[i] - 5 (> 0)
-4 -> 1  # A[i+1] = A[i] + 5 (<= 0)
1 -> -4  # A[i+1] = A[i] - 5 (> 0)
-4 -> 1  # A[i+1] = A[i] + 5 (<= 0)
etc.
```

so you'll never get an output of `"16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16"`.  Reread your problem and verify the rules.